# How to count all cards owned for a specific element in a card game documentation on excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, card

Sorry about the confusing title, but I don't know how better to state it. I have an excel sheet documenting these cards from a card game that works off elements. I have the excel sheet that records all the stats for all the cards I know about, with the card names in column A, how many I own of that card in column B, and what colour that card is in column C. And I have some totals down the bottom as total cards owned. Anyway, I want to make a total owned for each element, like fire cards owned 7. But there are lots of cards, and I'm regularly editing it, so I want to make it automatically tally all the blue cards I own, including duplicates. If it is impossible, I might have to go through the tally weekly, but I figured I'd at least post this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(Table of cards[column with card type]="Blue"),Table of cards[column with number of cards owned])

Edit: Maybe I should phrase it like this:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(Tbl[C]="Blue"),Tbl[B])

[This article explains it well](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function)

Comment: This was the perfect answer. tbh i didn't think there be an answer for such a specific problem

Comment: Glad I could help! Excel formulas can do lots of very specific things, you've just got to find the right one :)